# Unable to install log4php using composer

Tags: php, composer-php, log4php

I'm trying to deploy my PHP webapp on my ubuntu server.
running composer install ends with the following exception:

```
  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout 'https://git-wip- 
  us.apache.org/repos/asf/logging-log4php.git' 
  '/var/www/webapp/public_html/vendor/apache/log4php' && cd 
  '/var/www/webapp/public_html/vendor/apache/log4php' && git remote 
  add composer 'https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/logging-log4php.git' && git fetch composer                                                                            

  Cloning into '/var/www/webapp/public_html/vendor/apache/log4php'...                                                                                                                                      
  fatal: repository 'https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/logging-log4php.git/' not found
```

I've tried to add explicit repositories to the composer.json as below still with out any progress

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/apache/logging-log4php"
  }
],
"require": {
  "apache/log4php": "2.3.0",
  "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~6.0"
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[They've just migrated](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4PHP-242).

After you correct link to repository, do not forget to recreate your composer.lock file. Probably the simplest way is to delete it and run `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

Create a composer.json file with the following content:

```
{
    "require": {
        "apache/log4php": "^2.3.0"
    }
}
```

Run the Composer install procedure:

```
php composer.phar install
```

This will install Apache log4php in vendor/apache/log4php.

To use log4php simply include vendor/autoload.php in your script.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$log = Logger::getLogger("default");
$log->info("Hello !!");
```